# Properties determining boundedness of function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, optimization

The function I am looking at is

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx + b^Tx + c$$

where $A$ is a symmetric matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$  and $b,c$ belong to $\mathbb{R}^n$

I want to determine what properties must be established to tell if $f(x)$ is unbounded below or not.

I first began by proving that if $Ax + b = 0$ does not have a solution, then the function is unbounded below. I did this by looking at the gradient of $f$ and seeing that if $Ax + b = 0$ has no solution, then there is no local minimum, and therefore $f(x)$ has no lower bounds.

I now want to assess whether if $A$ is positive semidefinite is relevant to whether the function is or isn't bounded below. How can I make this assessment?

EDIT: I really just want to know what happens to the boundedness of  $ f(x) $ (specifically, whether it is bounded below or not) when  $ A $ is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: Lack of a local minimum is not enough to prove there is no lower bound.  For example, $x\mapsto 1/(1+x^2)$ has no local minimum, but is bounded below by $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Good point...so I should look at the limits then? Would that be the only thing I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for $A$, and $\lambda_i$ the corresponding eigenvalues.

Then $f(Ux) = {1 \over 2} x^T U^T A U x + (U^T b)^T x +c = {1 \over 2} \sum_k \lambda_k x_k^2 + \sum_k [U^Tb]_k x_k  +c$.

We see that if some $\lambda_k <0$ then $f$ is unbounded below.

We see that if some $\lambda_k = 0$, and $[U^Tb]_k \neq 0$, then $f$ is unbounded below. (Note that $[U^Tb]_k$ is the projection of $b$ along the $k$th eigenvector of $A$).

Otherwise $f$ is bounded below.